# Nested select in Spring JPA query when using Postrges

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

In Spring JPA repository I have a following method

```
@Query("select e from Entity e where e.enabled = true and e.id in :ids and (select count(*) from SubEntity se where se.e = e and se.date = :date) = 0")
    public Page<Entity> query(@Param("date") String date, @Param("ids") List<Long> ids, Pageable pageable);
```

When running this in h2 embedded database everything is fine, but when running this against Postgres I am getting following:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
  Position: 123
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Try logging the actual SQL run so you can see why the SQL is invalid.

Comment: Thank you for recommendation, there was just empty list of the ids being passed.